# As Tunisian, having Argentinean passport would it allow for more jobs abroad

Tags: europe, argentina

I've a Tunisian passport and was seeking to travel with my wife to Argentina to have our child born there so that we could get Argentinian passport.

I know that this passport offer much more mobility but will it allow me to find easier (or more) job opportunities.

FYI, I work abroad as expat and am looking for a passport that could allow me to get easily work permits in most/more countries.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how it would afford YOU (the father) more mobility? You would still have only Tunisian citizenship... Unless I misunderstood?

Comment: There are three main gateways to citizenship in Argentina: (a) being born there, (b) becoming naturalised, or (c) if one or both of your parents are Argentinian citizens. A period of residency is typically required for naturalisation. I doubt you can naturalise solely on the basis of your child being born there https://clond.cancilleria.gob.ar/en/content/argentine-citizenship. Work permits typically require a sponsor, the nationality of the applicant isn’t usually a criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get Argentine citizenship, you will be a citizen of a [Schengen Annex II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Nationals_of_'Annex_II'_countries_and_territories_(visa_waiver_countries)) (visa waiver) country. This will allow you to *travel* to the Schengen area, but not to *work* there.

An application for a work permit would look at your particular circumstances, your citizenship would be relatively less important than for travel.

Comment: O.M. Thanks for your answer.